# Sonarqube css: How to disable "Unexpected unknown type" rule for selectors with prefix "pr-"

Tags: css, angular, sonarqube

I am running sonarqube's CSS analyzer over my Angular 7 project and it is marking all references to material2 elements in my scss as critical bugs.

For example:

> Unexpected unknown type selector "mat-form-field"

How do I add exceptions for selectors with the "mat-" prefix using the sonar-project.properties file?

I've tried a number of different variations on what I've found [here](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-type-no-unknown/#ignoretypes-regex-regex-string)  but I've been unable to find an example of this done in a properties file.

I'm looking for something like this:

`sonar.css.selector-type-no-unknown.ignoreTypes=["/^mat-/"]`

Comment: Ticket is created to fix that https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-css/issues/151

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a parameter in StyleLint for that situation:

```
"rules": {
     "selector-type-no-unknown": [true, { "ignoreTypes": ["/^mat-/","/^retrace-/"] }]
  }
```

Comment: In which file do I change these rules...and where do I find this file?

Comment: @DhritimanTamuliSaikia read the docs on [configuration](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure).